# Aluminum Lua - register function

Tags: c#, methods, lua, aluminumlua

How do you register Lua method info (of static public void) to a context in AluminiumLua?

Comment: @Nicol  I presume it's https://github.com/chkn/AluminumLua

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by providing a delegate matching your method's signature.

```cs
using System;
using AluminumLua;

public delegate void HelloDelegate();

class Program
{
    public static void Hello()
    {
        Console.Write("Hello world!");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var context = new LuaContext();
        var obj = LuaObject.FromDelegate(new HelloDelegate(Hello));
        context.SetGlobal("hello", obj);
        context.Get("hello").AsFunction().Invoke(new LuaObject[] { });
    }
}
```